# installing go packages in linux

Tags: linux, installation, go

I am new at GO and just installed the latest version available for Linux AMD64, but although I can run go commands, I don't seem to be able to get, build or install any commands.

```
go get bufio
package bufio: unrecognized import path "bufio"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package ["bufio"](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/) is part of the standard library. You cannot "go get" it. But no worry, any standard and supported installation procedure makes this package installed (as is the whole stdlib), so there's no need to "go get" it.

Just include

```
import "bufio"
```

in a package where you want to use its exported decalarations and it should "just work" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Did you set **both** the GOROOT and GOBIN environmental variables as described in the [installation instructions](http://golang.org/doc/install#install)?

BTW, did you install it from source or the release tarball?

Comment: I also recommend installing the go compiler [from source](http://golang.org/doc/install/source), it compiles relatively fast and it makes easier keeping up with the updates.